# Google Calendar API v3 multiple events in one request (using C# server api)

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

What I'm trying is to send a batch of calendar events with one request using Google calendar client library for .Net. By the way, it has a very poor documentation and I still have no idea how to implement it. Everything i can do now is:  Insert event into the CalendarService.Events object and then Fetch it (one request per event). Does this api even provide such functionality for batch requests and if it do, can anyone show examples?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help you

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
        "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Calendar.Sample.Store"));
}

// Create the service.
var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API Sample",
    });

// Create a batch request.
var request = new BatchRequest(service);
request.Queue<CalendarList>(service.CalendarList.List(),
     (content, error, i, message) =>
     {
         // Put your callback code here.
     });
request.Queue<Event>(service.Events.Insert(
     new Event
     {
         Summary = "Learn how to execute a batch request",
         Start = new EventDateTime() { DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0) },
         End = new EventDateTime() { DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0) }
     }, "YOUR_CALENDAR_ID_HERE"),
     (content, error, i, message) =>
     {
         // Put your callback code here.
     });
// You can add more Queue calls here.

// Execute the batch request, which includes the 2 requests above.
await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

Extracted from: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/batch

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you about the terrible documentation, but after a lot of hacking around, I got this to work.  I wrote this up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21470528/349974) as an answer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019530/batch-processing-with-google-calendar-v3-api).